# Is there a way to enable IPVS proxy-mode on GKE cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kube-proxy

I want to try this new proxy mode and the various schedulers it has for some of our apps. So far I've been unable to find a way to change the default mode `iptables` to `ipvs` on GKE nodes.

Everywere says to pass `--proxy-mode=ipvs` to kube-proxy, but that does not make sense on "elastic/dynamic" deployments as GKE, new nodes would not take those changes.

I've also seen here: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/ that *"GCE scripts"* (which I don't really know what those are) support setting up `KUBE_PROXY_MODE=ipvs` environment variable, but I cannot find a way to pass env variables to node pools at creation time via `gcloud` or web interface.

Any idea if this is even possible ?
(by the way I'm using version `1.11.6-gke.2`)

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for IPVS on GKE . You can create your own cluster using Google Compute Engine instances and modify every aspect of your cluster as you want. You can use [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/) or even refer to the [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) repository by Kelsey Hightower.

Comment: I know the questions about GKE, but as a side not for the curious. I checked kube-proxy pod log on a AWS kops v1.11.9 cluster, it also uses iptables.